# how to reopen a closed socket in order to send message back to the client

Tags: java, android, sockets, networking, tcp

using DataInputStream to get an int and long sent from the Android client to this Java desktop server. After that a pdf file is received from the Android client. for a total of 3 files sent by the client to the Server.  the problem is when sending in the other direction.

i have to close both the input and output streams right after the while loop.  if i don't do that, the pdf file will be corrupted and the program will stop and get stuck on the while loop and not continue execution to the end of the thread.

if i have to close the input and output steams, the socket is getting closed.  how do i reopen the same socket?

i need to reopen the same socket because of the need to send a message back to the Android client that the server received the pdf file from to send it a confirmation that the file was safely received by the server.

there are multiple Android clients connected to the same single Java server, so i imagine that the same socket is needed to send a message back to the client.  without the socket it would be difficult to determine which client to send the message to.

```
       byte[] buffer = new byte[fileSizeFromClient];

        while((count = dis.read(buffer)) > 0){
            bos.write(buffer, 0, count);
        }

       dis.close();  // closes DataInputStream dis
       bos.close();  // closes BufferedOutputStream bos
```

EDIT:

code from the client

```
   dos.writeInt((int)length); // sends the length as number bytes is file size to the server
   dos.writeLong(serial); // sends the serial number to the server

                int count = 0; // number of bytes

                while ((count = bis.read(bytes)) > 0) {
                    dos.write(bytes, 0, count);
                }

     dos.close(); // need to close outputstream or result is incomplete file sent to server
                  // and the server hangs, stuck on the while loop
                  // if dos is closed then the server sends error free file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can't reopen a socket. You have to make a new one. You don't have to close your socket once you're done with your file transfer. The server can still reuse it send your message reply. Since you've already sent the file size, your server can use that to know when your client is done sending the complete file. After that, your server can send your reply to the client.

Try this for your current loop.

```
 int bytesRead = 0;
 while((count = dis.read(buffer)) > 0 && bytesRead != fileSizeFromClient){
  bytesRead += count; 
  bos.write(buffer, 0, count);
 }
 bos.close();
 //don't close the input stream
```

Comment: i tried this code and for some reason every time the file arrives incomplete.  smaller than the actual size.

Comment: @Kevik how are you sending the file size to the server? What's your client's code?

Comment: file size is sent from client and received with no problems at the server, and was verified with System.out.println on the server, if i don't close the outstreams (which also closes the server) it will result in incomplete and corrupted pdf file received and it will become stuck at a deadlock on the server side while loop

Comment: This code isn't correct. It iterates once too often, and it is liable to read too many bytes on the last correct iteration. You need to reverse the tests; add a test for 'count != 0'; and use something like (int)Math.min(buffer.length, fileSizeFromClient-bytesRead) as the length parameter to the read() method.